# Query Multiple Custom Post Types & Exclude a Taxonomy Term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, customization, query-posts, taxonomy

I'm querying multiple custom posts types and I'd like to filter certain posts that are tagged with a specific taxonomy term.

The taxonomy is "content" and the term is "indy"

I'm using the the code below.

```
<?php

// The Query
query_posts( array('post_type' => 'post', 'videos', 'music') );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php endwhile;
// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

How can I add that filter?

Comment: is this the main query, or an additional query? what page is this query on? if this is the main query, have a look at [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). also see [taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) and [post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters) parameters for `WP_Query`.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the arguments of [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). The following arguments should be what you need. Note that `tax_query` takes an array of arrays.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array( 'post', 'videos', 'music' ),
  'tax_query' => array(
     array(
       'taxonomy' => 'content',
       'field'    => 'slug',
       'terms'    => 'indy',
       'operator' => 'NOT IN' 
     )
   )
);

$myquery = new WP_Query( $args );
while( $myquery->have_posts() ):
  $myquery->the_post();
  # do your stuff here
endwhile;
```